# Which is correct: "What lurks underneath ARE our lives," or "What lurks underneath IS our lives"?

Tags: verbs, pronouns, determiners, agreement, what

I admit, the fact I can't figure this out is embarrassing.  I'm not looking to change the wording of the sentence, but rather want an answer to which is the correct verb tense in this exact instance.  Since "lives" is plural, then "are" should be the corresponding verb, one might argue.  On the other hand, something seems intuitively amiss about that choice.  Perhaps "what IS lurking underneath (IS) our lives is  causing confusion for me, as I try to sort this out (I think "what" is being used as a singular pronoun.  Or is it?  Maybe it's being used as a determiner.)  Maybe "our lives" is one singular concept that should match to a singular verb.  I'm going down a rabbit hole here and can't seem to get out.  Help!  Any assistance is appreciated!

Confusing examples that I've considered (that aren't helping) -
What time ARE we going?
What time IS it?
(What is determining the verbs "are" and "is" in the above examples?!)  Please help before I go insane!

Comment: This question has been answered on ELL; here is the link to the question and its answers:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/226699/subject-verb-agreement-noun-clauses

Comment: Thank you for the referenced link, which did somewhat help.  Would love to hear comments on my final paragraph (in my original post, paragraph that starts  "Confusing examples..."). "What time" is sometimes being treated as singular and as plural in differing usages.  Is this because 1.  "What time are we going" indicates choosing from several different time answers and, 2.  "what time is it" indicates a singluar choice (because there is only one answer) and therefore takes a singular verb?

Comment: I posted the full answer I had ready when I found the reference on ELL, which reference induced me to believe that my explanations would not have added much. I only made a few modifications to it. There is only one answer, you say, but the comments do provide directives to be given some thought, for instance the question of the default value for "what" (user BillJ's comments, I believe). Comments are often partial answers or even sometimes full answers.

Comment: 'What time are we going?' parallels 'When are we going?'; the agreement obviously has to be _are ... we_.  'What time is it' corresponds in a looser way to 'What **is** the time?'

Answer (score 0):

The confusing examples stated at the end of the question have nothing to do with this question; in the first "what time" is an adverbial, the subject of the verb is "we" and so there is only one possibility for the number: plural; in the second "what time" is a subject complement (*It is 5 o'clock.*) and "it" is the subject, so that no other number than singular is possible.

In this sentence (What lurks…) "what" is a pronoun; it can be felt that it is the subject of the verb "lurk" and a subject can't be a determiner; a subject can be a noun or something noun-like, as a pronoun (put in the place of a noun). A determiner is used before a noun.

"What", in this sentence, is a relative pronoun (CoGEL p. 1056 § **15.8**) that functions as subject of the verb "lurk";  the clause in which it is subject, that is, "what lurks underneath" is a nominal clause; this means that it answers syntactically to the characteristics of a noun or noun phrase, although not perfectly; for instance they can't be modified by adjectives nor can determiners be used with them.

- <s>**The red** *what you planted in the garden* are beautiful.</s>

However, from the point of view of whatever  nature they can be seen to have, the fact that they can always be replaced by a noun phrase that means the same thing is a first indication of their nominal nature (this noun phrase can however be quite complex); from the point of view of the function that a constituent may have in a clause, they have all the functions nouns may have:

- Subject: *What you see* is the end. (*the* ***spectacle*** *before your eyes*)
- Direct object: He gave *what he had*. (*the* ***whole*** *of his possession*)
- Indirect object: They gave to *what was being discussed* a lot of attention. (*the* ***discussion***)
- Subject complement: The warm season is *what they are waiting for*. (*the* ***object*** *of their waiting*)
- Appositive: A fatal incident, *what you had expected all along*, finally took place without anyone being able to do anything about it. (*a likely* ***possibility*** *of which you were aware*)

This is what justifies the nomenclature, and the belief the majority of grammarians have that these units do stand for something  which, in principle could referred to by a bare noun (someone would first have to coin it by defining it as having the characteristics that can be read in the nominal phrase // however, for a vast number of cases not realistic).

The problem here is not in the word "what"; I do think that there is a difficulty, but I think it is a matter to be investigated at the level of the  nominal clause (what lurks underneath), it being the subject of the verb "to be".

This has been touched upon above, nominal clauses have essentially the nature of the noun, but they are not as perfectly nouns as true nouns. They can't be modified by adjectives; as well they can't be given the characteristic of plural number: the mark of number (appending of a final s) can't be added to them. This means that, basically, they have to be considered as having generally only the singular or perhaps no number, as for mass nouns. The question of considering that those nominal entities could sometimes be singular (as "sun", "horizon",…) and sometimes only plural (as "people", "the rich",…) is not much discussed; it is obvious that the attribution of a number would be dependent on a case by case semantic analysis and on what the speaker intends (*The committee is deliberating. — The committee are at lunch.*); I could find nothing about that subject.